# Simple as2 load into an as3 movie

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript-2

I'm loading an as2 game into a as3 movie. No communication other than to play the game in the movie. I'm using a loader class.

```
function startLoad()
{
    var mRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(correctURL.toString());
    mLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onCompleteHandler);
    mLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onProgressHandler);
    mLoader.load(">http://www.boomerang-tv.ro/sites/www.boomerang-tv.ro/files/flash/data/Scooby_Doo_-_Downhill_Dash/scoobydownhill-BM.swf");
}

function onCompleteHandler(loadEvent:Event)
{
    addChild(loadEvent.currentTarget.content);
}
```

When it finishes loading I get this error.

> ArgumentError: Error #2180: It is illegal to move AVM1 content (AS1 or
>   AS2) to a different part of the displayList when it has been loaded
>   into AVM2 (AS3) content.  at
>   flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/addChild()  at
>   main_fla::MainTimeline/onCompleteHandler()

Any ideas. I'm sure its simple it's just late :(

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding the loader instead of the loader content.

```
function onCompleteHandler(loadEvent:Event) 
{ 
   addChild(loadEvent.currentTarget.loader); 
}
```